# ¿Cómo reordenar filas al hacer clic en cabeceras de tabla usando DataTable de BootStrap?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, bootstrap, datatables

Estoy usando DataTable en una tabla, pero no puedo reordenar las filas de estas al hacer click en las cabeceras de la tabla.

¿Cómo puedo solucionar esto? ... Si se dan cuenta en la imagen en las cabezeras no salen las flechitas respectivas que indican reordenacion.

Código JS

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $.noConflict();
        $('#tableAsistencia').DataTable({
            language: {
                "lengthMenu": "Mostrar _MENU_ registros",
                "zeroRecords": "No se encontraron resultados",
                "info": "Mostrando registros del _START_ al _END_ de un total de _TOTAL_ registros",
                "infoEmpty": "Mostrando registros del 0 al 0 de un total de 0 registros",
                "infoFiltered": "(filtrado de un total de _MAX_ registros)",
                "sSearch": "Buscar:",
                "oPaginate": {
                    "sFirst": "Primero",
                    "sLast": "Último",
                    "sNext": "Siguiente",
                    "sPrevious": "Anterior"
                },
                "sProcessing": "Procesando...",
            },
            //para usar los botones
            orderCellsTop: true,
            responsive: "true",
            dom: 'Bfrtilp',
            buttons: [
                {
                    extend: 'excelHtml5',
                    text: '<i class="fas fa-file-excel"></i> ',
                    titleAttr: 'Exportar a Excel',
                    className: 'btn btn-success',
                    value: 'Excel'
                },
                {
                    extend: 'pdfHtml5',
                    text: '<i class="fas fa-file-pdf"></i> ',
                    titleAttr: 'Exportar a PDF',
                    className: 'btn btn-danger'
                },
                {
                    extend: 'print',
                    text: '<i class="fa fa-print"></i> ',
                    titleAttr: 'Imprimir',
                    className: 'btn btn-info'
                },

            ],
        });

    });

function GetAsistencia() {
    var fecha = $('#fecha').val();
    var grado = $("#grado option:selected").text();
    var grupo = $("#grupo option:selected").text();

    console.log(fecha + grado + grupo);
    if (fecha ==='' || grado === '' || grupo === '') {
        alert('Seleccione fecha, grado y grupo');
        return false;
    }

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/Procesor/GetAsistencia",
        datatype: "json",
        data: {fecha: fecha, grado: grado, grupo: grupo},
        success: function (data) {
          data = JSON.parse(data); 
          CrearTabla(data);
        },
        complete: function () {
            TablaPlus();
            console.log('GetAsistencia');
        }
    });
    return false;
}


function CrearTabla(emp) {
    $('#tableAsistencia tbody tr').remove();
        var estado = null;
        $.each(emp, function (index, item) {
            if (item.Status === true) estado = 'Asistente'; else estado = 'Inasistente';
            let tr = `<tr> 
                      <td style="text-align: center;"> ${index + 1} </td>
                      <td style="text-align: justify;"> ${item.Nombre} </td>
                      <td style="text-align: justify;"> ${item.Apellido} </td>
                      <td style="text-align: justify;"> ${item.Email} </td>
                      <td style="text-align: justify;"> ${item.Materia} </td>
                      <td style="text-align: justify;"> ${estado} </td>
                      <td style="text-align: center;"> <input type="button" value="Editar" class="btn btn-primary" style="width:80px;" onclick="PreventEdit('${item.Id}','${item.Dni}','${item.Materia}','${item.Status}','${item.Email}','${item.Foto}','${item.DniAdm}');"> </td>
                      </tr >`;
            $('#tableAsistencia tbody').append(tr);
        });
}

function TablaPlus() {
    $('#tableAsistencia').DataTable();

}
```

Código HTML

```
<script src="~/Content/datatables/datatables.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="~/Content/datatables/datatables.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="~/Content/datatables/Buttons-1.6.1/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="~/Content/datatables/JSZip-2.5.0/jszip.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="~/Content/datatables/pdfmake-0.1.36/pdfmake.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="~/Content/datatables/pdfmake-0.1.36/vfs_fonts.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="~/Content/datatables/Buttons-1.6.1/js/buttons.html5.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.2/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-oS3vJWv+0UjzBfQzYUhtDYW+Pj2yciDJxpsK1OYPAYjqT085Qq/1cq5FLXAZQ7Ay" crossorigin="anonymous">


    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12">
                <div class="table-responsive">
                    <table id="tableAsistencia" class="table table-bordered table-hover">
                        <thead>
                            <tr style="background-color:gainsboro;">
                                <th >Nª</th>
                                <th >Nombre</th>
                                <th >Apellido</th>
                                <th >Email</th>
                                <th >Materia</th>
                                <th >Estado</th>
                                <th></th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Has intentado algo?

Comment: orderCellsTop: true,   intente asiii

Comment: me refiero a que si has intentado ver la documentación oficial...

Answer (score 0):

Te hace falta habilitar la opción de order, la documentación oficial lo tiene en sus ejemplos, revisa el siguiente código:

```
$('#tableAsistencia').DataTable({
    language: {
        "lengthMenu": "Mostrar _MENU_ registros",
        "zeroRecords": "No se encontraron resultados",
        "info": "Mostrando registros del _START_ al _END_ de un total de _TOTAL_ registros",
        "infoEmpty": "Mostrando registros del 0 al 0 de un total de 0 registros",
        "infoFiltered": "(filtrado de un total de _MAX_ registros)",
        "sSearch": "Buscar:",
        "oPaginate": {
            "sFirst": "Primero",
            "sLast": "Último",
            "sNext": "Siguiente",
            "sPrevious": "Anterior"
        },
        "sProcessing": "Procesando...",
    },
    //Para tener el click habilitado de la cabecera que permite ordenar ascendente y descendentemente:
    //https://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/table_sorting.html
    "order": [[ 3, "desc" ]],

    //para usar los botones
    orderCellsTop: true,
    responsive: "true",
    dom: 'Bfrtilp',
    buttons: [
        {
            extend: 'excelHtml5',
            text: '<i class="fas fa-file-excel"></i> ',
            titleAttr: 'Exportar a Excel',
            className: 'btn btn-success',
            value: 'Excel'
        },
        {
            extend: 'pdfHtml5',
            text: '<i class="fas fa-file-pdf"></i> ',
            titleAttr: 'Exportar a PDF',
            className: 'btn btn-danger'
        },
        {
            extend: 'print',
            text: '<i class="fa fa-print"></i> ',
            titleAttr: 'Imprimir',
            className: 'btn btn-info'
        },

    ],
});
```

Documentación oficial: https://datatables.net/reference/